# Why is this sql statement super slow?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am writing large amounts of data to a sqlite database. I am using a temporary dataframe to find unique values.

This sql code takes forever in `conn.execute(sql)`

```
if upload_to_db == True:
    print(f'########################################WRITING TO TEMP TABLE: {symbol} #######################################################################')
    master_df.to_sql(name='tempTable', con=engine, if_exists='replace')

    with engine.begin() as cn:
        sql = """INSERT INTO instrumentsHistory (datetime, instrumentSymbol, observation, observationColName)
                SELECT t.datetime, t.instrumentSymbol, t.observation, t.observationColName
                FROM tempTable t
                WHERE NOT EXISTS 
                    (SELECT 1 FROM instrumentsHistory f
                     WHERE t.datetime = f.datetime
                     AND t.instrumentSymbol = f.instrumentSymbol
                     AND t.observation = f.observation
                     AND t.observationColName = f.observationColName)"""
        print(f'##############################################WRITING TO FINAL TABLE: {symbol} #################################################################')

        cn.execute(sql)
```

running this takes forever to write to the database. Can someone help me understand how to speed it up?

---

Edit 1:

How many rows roughly? -About 15,000 at a time. Basically it is pulling data into a pandas dataframe and making some transformations and then writing it to a sqlite database. there are probably 600 different instruments and each having like 15,000 rows so 9M rows ultimately. Give or take a million....

Comment: What is your SQL engine (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your SQL database, you could try using something like `INSERT INTO IGNORE` (MySQL), or `MERGE` (e.g. on Oracle), which would do the insert only if it would not violate a primary key or unique constraint.  This would assume that such a constraint would exist on the 4 columns which you are checking.

In the absence of merge, you could try adding the following index to the `instrumentsHistory` table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON instrumentsHistory (datetime, instrumentSymbol, observation,
                                        observationColName);
```

This index would allow for rapid lookup of each incoming record, coming from the `tempTable`, and so might speed up the insert process.

Comment: So, I should create the index before the query?

Comment: Yes ... if you want the index to be available during the insert.

Comment: I'm getting this error `OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) index idx already exists`

Comment: If that error message is to be believed, then there is already an index by the name of `idx`.  In this case, try using some other name.

Answer (score 0):

This subquery

```sql
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT 1 FROM instrumentsHistory f
         WHERE t.datetime = f.datetime
         AND t.instrumentSymbol = f.instrumentSymbol
         AND t.observation = f.observation
         AND t.observationColName = f.observationColName)
```

has to check *every* row in the table - and match four columns - until a match is found.  In the worst case, there is no match and a full table scan must be completed.  Therefore, the performance of the query will deteriorate as the table grows in size.

The solution, as mentioned in Tim's answer, is to create an index over the four columns to that the db can quickly determine whether a match exists.